# Can a Ruby object allocated in a C extension get reaped at anytime?

Tags: c, ruby

So this might be a dumb question, but I'm unsure about the exact GC behavior with Ruby extensions.  For example, if I call `rb_hash_new` in a C function and then begin to do some processing on it before returning the value back to Ruby code, could the logic get interrupted midway and the Ruby hash gets reaped by the GC?  Example code below.

```
VALUE my_function(VALUE rb_self) {
    VALUE hash = rb_hash_new();
    // Do some stuff with hash
    return hash;
}
```

Could the hash in the above example get deallocated before it returns?  If so, is the only way to prevent this to make sure all allocated Ruby objects get marked by the function passed to `Data_Wrap_Struct` no matter what, even if they are only used temporarily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible that GC will run during '*Do some stuff with hash*' if in that block you create other Ruby objects, eg. via `rb_str_new`, `rb_ary_new`, or if you use ruby-memory allocation functions.

To mark the object as 'busy' for the garbage collector, use:

```
rb_gc_register_address(VALUE *var);
```

To remove the object from the list of 'busy' objects, use:

```
rb_gc_unregister_address(VALUE *var);
```

Comment: Thanks, I wish there was more documentation for this!